# Prove that $k = \pm 1$ if $\lim_{\theta \to 0} k \theta \ \mathrm{cosec}\ \theta = \lim_{\theta \to 0} \theta \ \mathrm{cosec} \ k \theta$

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

This question has confused me for a long time. I would appreciate a brief proof, though a longer proof for deeper comprehension is welcome.

I am given that
$$
 \lim_{\theta \to 0} k \theta \ \mathrm{cosec}\  \theta
 = \lim_{\theta \to 0} \theta \ \mathrm{cosec} \ k \theta
$$

**How do I prove that $k = \pm 1$?**

EDIT: *There was an error in my textbook. Corrected the right hand side limit.*

Comment: Are you sure?  The limit of the left-hand side is $k$; the right-hand side is unbounded unless $k=0$.

Comment: $\lim_{\theta \to 0} (cosec \ k \theta)$ doesn't exist.

Comment: Please do not down vote for that, this is the question given in my textbook. Is the question erroneous or is there a possible answer?

Comment: There is definitely a mistake in the book. Are you sure limit on the RHS isn't of $\theta\text{cosec }k\theta$?

Comment: @Wojowu No, I definitely copied it correctly. Error in the book it is, then. Should I delete?

Comment: @VedantChandra probably should

Comment: What is the book?

Comment: @Did Something called 'Frank ISC Mathematics'. Indian school board books aren't exactly world class..

Comment: The correct exercise might be to show the implication: $$
 \lim_{\theta \to 0} k \theta \, \mathrm{cosec}\,  \theta
 = \lim_{\theta \to 0} \theta\,\mathrm{cosec} \, k \theta\implies k=\pm1.
$$ 
Can you solve this?

Comment: @Did My textbook obviously left out the RHS $\theta$, I've edited it in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Answer for the original question

In order $\csc(k\theta)$ makes sense, we have to assume $k\ne0$ throughout.

Since
$$
\lim_{\theta\to0}\theta\csc\theta=
\lim_{\theta\to0}\frac{\theta}{\sin\theta}=1
$$
the left-hand side has limit $k$.

On the other hand,
$$
\lim_{\theta\to0^+}\csc(k\theta)=
\begin{cases}
\infty & \text{if $k>0$}\\
-\infty & \text{if $k<0$}
\end{cases}
$$
For the limit $\theta\to0^-$, exchange $\infty$ with $-\infty$ in the above.

So there's no value of $k$ where these limits are the same.

### Answer for the edited question

If the right-hand side is $\lim_{\theta\to0}\theta\csc(k\theta)$, we can say
$$
\lim_{\theta\to0}\theta\csc(k\theta)=
\lim_{\theta\to0}\frac{\theta}{\sin(k\theta)}=
\frac{1}{k}\lim_{\theta\to0}\frac{k\theta}{\sin(k\theta)}=
\frac{1}{k}
$$
Now, equality of the limits gives
$$
k=\frac{1}{k}
$$
so $k=\pm1$.

Comment: Beautifully complete answer! Thank you!